# Searching for a formula

Tags: feature-request, search

In reference to a [previous comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10169/how-to-search-for-a-formula-expression), I was wondering about integrating [MathWebSearch](http://trac.mathweb.org/MWS) with SE.math.